# force nginx to write an empty/blank http authorization request header

Tags: nginx, header, request, authorization

I want my Nginx server to inject a blank/empty Authorization request header i.e. "authorization": ""

I'm trying to use:

```
proxy_set_header Authorization '';
```

Unfortunately the previous directive doesn't set any request header, Is this possible to do?. I need to be able to set its value to an empty string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That might not be possible with NGINX. From [proxy_set_header definition](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_set_header):

> If the value of a header field is an empty string then this field will not be passed to a proxied server